# Find a function $f : (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is bijective.

Tags: functions

Note that any interval in this post of the form $(a, b) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : a < x < b \}$.

I am having a hard time trying to answer this. I just can not seem to think of a function that maps from $(0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$. I tried graphing the $\tan \theta$ function on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) but was unable to "squeeze" it so the domain was $(0, 1)$.

Any help is greatly appreciative. Thanks!

Comment: $e^{1/x}$ might be a guess?

Comment: $\tan{( \pi(x-\frac 12))}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried graphing the tanθ function on Desmos but was unable to "squeeze" it so the domain was (0,1)

But thats just shifting and squeezing.

$\tan(x):(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)\to  \mathbb R \to (-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$

So $\tan(x-\frac \pi 2): (0, \pi)\to \mathbb R $.

So $\tan(\pi(x-\frac \pi 2)): (0,1) \to \mathbb R$.

.......

Note...  You can *always* squeeze and shift $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ via:

$x -a : (a,b)\mapsto (0, b-a)$

$\frac {x-a}{b-a}: (a,b)\mapsto (0, 1)$.

$\frac {x-a}{b-a}\cdot (d-c): (a,b) \mapsto (0, d-c)$

And finally $\frac {x-a}{b-a}(d-c) + c: (a,b) \mapsto (c, d)$

.......

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$
tan(-\pi/2) = -\infty\\
tan(\pi/2) = \infty\\
$$

Also note:

$$
\pi · 1 - \pi/2 = \pi/2\\
\pi · 0 - \pi/2 = -\pi/2
$$

This should be enough to build yourselft the example. If not, note that 'squeeze' function *s(x)* from *(a,b)* to *(c,d)* follows this expression:

$$
s(x) = \frac{d-c}{b-a} ( x -a) + c
$$

Then

$$
f(x) = tan(s(x))
$$

Answer (score 1):

How about $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x} $$

In general, for real numbers $a,b$ with $a<b$ we have $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x-b} $$ being bijective.

Here is a [desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/egtwe8yfrt).

Note that $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\to(a,b)$ is given by

$$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{\left(a+b\right)x+2}{2x}-\frac{\sqrt{(ax-bx)^2+4}}{2x} $$